# Como mandar los datos de un modal hacia un recyclerview que esta en otro activity sin usar base de datos

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Android y quiero crear una sección de favoritos. Para ello quiero agregar un floatting action button (fab) y que al presionarlo se envíen los datos que tengo hacia un `ListView` en otro `Activity`.

Importante, no estoy usando base de datos.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Cuando tienes una Activity en primer plano ejecutándose, las otras Activities que te hayas creado en el proyecto no existen, no están en ejecución, así que no, no puedes pasarle la información a otro Activity. Podrás guardar esa información en alguna variable que utilice la Activity que tiene el ListView para que la use cuando tenga que volver a crearse al volver a ejecutar esa Activity.

Comment: Este como harias eso si me pudieras dar un ejemplo he visto que algunos usan sharedpreference pero no se muy bien cmo hacerlo